# How come I'm getting this Python error in my code?

Tags: python

```
import urllib, urllib2
def URLRequest(url, params, method="GET"):
    if method == "POST":
        return urllib2.Request(url, data=urllib.encode(params))  <<<< 31
    else:
        return urllib2.Request(url + "?" + urllib.encode(params))
```

'module' object has no attribute 'encode', line 31

Comment: The function name is `urlencode` not `encode`, so you would call `urllib.urlencode(params)`

Comment: @Jarret: That should be an answer ;)

Comment: The error message is pretty clear, no? If `urllib` has no attribute `encode`, that means that there is no `encode` function in `urllib`!

Comment: @BoltClock... heh heh, you're right, I was just too lazy to look up the link to the function in the API. Duly answered (with link)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The error message is correct: the `urllib` module does not have an `encode()` function. The function name is `urlencode()`, so you would call:

```
urllib.urlencode(params)
```

Python docs for the function: http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlencode

Comment: Here you go, 10 rep from me :D